# If 'h' be the height of a pyramid standing on a base which is an equilateral triangle of side 'a' units, then what is the slant height?

Tags: geometry

If 'h' be the height of a pyramid standing on a base which is an equilateral triangle of side 'a' units, then what is the slant height?

What I did:-

We know in equilateral triangle height= $\sqrt3/2*(side)^2$= $\sqrt3/2*a^2$
Total height= h+$\sqrt3/2*a^2$
base=a/2
Applying pythagoras

$(h+\sqrt3/2*a^2)^2+a^2/4$
It should give me the answer $\sqrt (h^2+a^2/3)$

Where I am wrong

Comment: Hmm....sorry Can you explain the logic in your answer pls? What's  that total height in your answer mean?

Comment: And you sure that the answer is $\sqrt {h^2+\frac{a^2}{3}} $? Bcoz am getting the ans to be $\sqrt {h^2+\frac{a^2}{4}} $

Comment: @shwetha how are you getting that answer? I am getting the same answer as op provided, although it may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The altitude $AB$ of pyramid will intersect base at the *centroid* $B$ of base-equilateral triangle. and the distance of centroid $BC$ from a vertex of base is $\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}$. You can verify this using pythagorean theorem or simple trigonometry.

[image]

Thus we have to apply pythagoras theorem on the $\triangle ABC$ whose legs are $AB = h$ and $BC = \frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}$ So the hypotenuse, ie, slant height $AC$ is :
$$s=\sqrt{h^2 + \frac{a^2}{3}}$$

Comment: hey, @samjoe can you explain it using a diagram

Comment: @CruziSeku I have edited. Please have a look now!